# PHP equivalent of Python’s dict.update

Tags: php

Python allows to update a dictionary (i.e., an “associative array” in PHP speak) in-place like so:

```py
mydict = {'banana': 'yellow', 'apple': 'green', 'blueberry': 'blue'}
mydict.update({'apple': 'red', 'orange': 'orange'})
```

The closest I have come to matching this in PHP is:

```php
$mydict = ['banana' => 'yellow', 'apple' => 'green', 'blueberry' => 'blue'];
$mydict = array_merge($mydict, ['apple' => 'red', 'orange' => 'orange']);
```

As a proponent of DRY, I don’t like having to type `$mydict` twice.  Is there a concise way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. The closest you'll get is the array union operator `+`:

```
$mydict = ['banana' => 'yellow', 'apple' => 'green', 'blueberry' => 'blue'];
$mydict += ['apple' => 'red', 'orange' => 'orange'];
```

However, this does **not replace** existing keys, so works differently than an `array_merge`. If you have two variables instead of literals, you could reserve their order though to get the overwriting effect:

```
$mydict = [...];
$newvalues = [...];

$newvalues += $mydict;
```

That's as close as you'll get with built-in methods.

Answer (score 1):

array is a primitive type. To access it in an object orientated way you can wrap it by extending [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php). Pay attention that the result is an object, not an array. so checks with is_array() will fail.

```
class MyArray extends ArrayObject
{
    public function update(array  $value)
    {
        $this->exchangeArray(array_merge($this->getArrayCopy(),$value));
    }
}

$mydict = ['banana' => 'yellow', 'apple' => 'green', 'blueberry' => 'blue'];
$mydict2 = ['apple' => 'red', 'orange' => 'orange'];

$ta = new MyArray($mydict);

$ta->update($mydict2);

print_r($ta);
```

this will produce

```
MyArray Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [banana] => yellow
            [apple] => red
            [blueberry] => blue
            [orange] => orange
        )

)
```